# Privacy policy changed in iOS 10, do we need re-submit our app?

Tags: ios, ios10

Since iOS 10 has changed its privacy police i.e. we need put privacy description in the plist file.

There is a question, are we needed to re-submit our app again after iOS 10 offically published?

As the plist need to be changed or apps would be crashed.

Anyone has any idea or info to help me fingure this?

Comment: Haven't checked the specific details on this one yet, but the usual way this works is that apps compiled against previous SDKs continue to work as before, while only apps compiled against the iOS 10 SDK will require those additions.

Comment: I dont think we need to re-sbumit the app. Just that the next version you upload must have that particular change. Apple wont suddenly start crashing the apps.

Answer (score 0):

What I found in my investigation is if we build the app from Xcode7 we don't have issue in the new privacy settings, For example if I am trying to access Camera or Photo Library it will not crash.

But if I build the app using Xcode8 it crashes saying the "Privacy description to access Camera / Photo Library is missing".

So its clear that we don't need to re-submit the app only for this privacy update.While submitting the next version (probably you need to use new Xcode8) makesure you added this privavcy policy update.